# How to decode SAML?

Tags: http, encoding, saml

I would decode this message sent to our national tax office. I have no clue how to start it. Seems it is a SAML encoding, I do not know much about SAML.

But in the content either xml or json is.

[image]

[image]

I tried this website to decode, but it did not do it.

https://www.samltool.com/decode.php

How to decode?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP-Redirect binding uses the DEFLATE encoding. The SAML message has been sent using the HTTP-Post binding. This means that the form data will include either a SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse form variable. This form variable must first be URL-decoded and then base-64 decoded to get the resultant XML.